# Can String.format remove numbers if they are zero?

Tags: java, string, formatting, format, string-formatting

I am building a stopwatch and I want to only display a field for the hours if they are >0.
At the moment I solve it like this, is there a shorter way?

```
String timeLeftFormatted = "";
    if (hours > 0) {
        timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    } else {
        timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    }
```

Comment: Well partly. It's pretty huge and I didn't find my question on SO, so I thought it would be a good idea to have the answer available here.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, the simplest way I can think of is something like:

`timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
            "%s:%02d:%02d", hours > 0 ? String.valueOf(hours) : "", minutes, seconds);`

Edit:

In a similar fashion, you could also modify the unformatted string itself based on whether `hours` is more than zero.

Comment: Thank you. Do You know if the formatter has a way to express this directly in the format string?

Comment: There are padding and leading space options for decimal conversions, but not to include/discard conversions based on value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a *trick*, using `argument_index`.

The documentation of the [format string syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) shows that *format specifiers* have the following syntax:

`%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`

By using `argument_index`, you can skip unused arguments, i.e. with a fixed argument list, you can substitute the format string itself to only use some of the values.

Using your example, and a ternary conditional operator, shown one line per argument for clarity:

```
String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(
        Locale.getDefault(),
        (hours > 0 ? "%1$d:%2$02d:%3$02d" : "%2$02d:%3$02d"),
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds
);
```

It could also be written like this:

```
String timeLeftFormatted = String.format((hours > 0 ? "%1$d:" : "") + "%2$02d:%3$02d",
                                         hours, minutes, seconds);
```